# In a strong field, how long would it take for domains to align?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How fast is the rate of "switch" for the domains to align with an exterior field? Possibly in milliseconds? 
I assume it won't take much time since domains are very small, and they only turn from a certain degree to another.

I know this would depend on a lot of factors, but if powerful large magnet can attract a ferromagnet with a force of nearly 4,000, brining it closer to it would take 0.005 seconds, then surely the magnetization was a lot faster than that. Since magnetization occurs before attraction.

Comment: Slightly off topic but related and interesting: http://www.matesy.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=153&Itemid=90&lang=en and the top video on the page http://motionmountain.net/videos.html

Answer (score 1):

http://news.sciencemag.org/math/2012/02/hot-idea-faster-hard-drive : "Each bit in a magnetic recording medium is in fact a nanometer-sized patch or "domain" that can be magnetized in either of two directions—say, up and down—to encode a 0 or a 1. That information is read out by the read head, a tiny electromagnet that passes over the rotating disk and measures each domain's orientation. The same head also writes the information to the disk by applying a magnetic field that flips a bit's orientation. But the traditional electromagnetic read head struggles to keep up. For a while now, the time needed to write one bit has been stuck at about 1 nanosecond, limiting the rate of data transfer."

Comment: A NANOSECOND! THAT'S UNBELIEVABLE. Magnetization could be that fast or a bit more... amazing.

Comment: And it's struggling as well, this is mind boggling!

Comment: @XCIX: "Today’s widely used mass storage devices, based on magnetic domain flipping by the giant magnetoresistance(GMR) effect (1,2), are limited to access times in the nanosecond range. (http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1280 )

Comment: @XCIX: "Traditionally, magnetization dynamics was studied under quasi-equilibrium conditions and thought of as a rather slow process, limited to the nanosecond regime [1] by domain-wall motion and spin–lattice relaxation time." http://www.physik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/hillebrands/Internal/Book_chapters/Spin_Dynamics_II/chap07_Rasing_etal.pdf

Comment: This is beyond my current level of understanding. But thank you for point out how fast domain's flip. Wow, in the nanosecond rage... Remarkable.

Comment: It is not so surprising. Even for the biggest ones, measuring $0.1 mm$ (and that is huge), the light can travel through in half a picosecond. In other words: the light (and ergo the information and the magnetic field) can go back and forth tenths of thousands of times in the time it takes for it to flip. Personally, a nanosecond feels slow to me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above quoted evaluations for the magnetization switching, but a precisse calculation concerns solving the Landau–Lifshitz–Gilbert equation (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation) 
and particullarly knowing the value of the damping factor alfa. The phenomenological character of this parameter is a great difficulty and only experimental works and numerical simulations can elucidate this issue. Fortunately, there are now several works that point values in the region of microwaves.